# Form Builder prefix

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form like this one:

```
<%= form_for People::Selector::GenderReportForm.new, url: selector_download_path do |f| %>

   <%= f.text_field :name %>

   <%= select_month(Date.today, 
       {field_name: 'start_month', 
        prefix: "people_selector_gender_report_form"},
       {class: "form-control"}) %>

<% end %>
```

From my point of view the `prefix: "people_selector_gender_report_form"` should be also be able to get from the resource: `People::Selector::GenderReportForm.new`

**Is there a way to build the same form without the `prefix`?** 
 Or is for example something like `prefix: f.prefix` possible? Thanks

Comment: instead of prefix, what you want there? Also what do you mean by `prefix: f.prefix`?

Comment: @ArupRakshit is there a method to get the  prefix `"people_selector_gender_report_form"` so that I do not have to paste the string?

Comment: I am still not sure, what do you mean by *Is there a way to build the same form without the prefix?*. Are you looking for the same _prefix_ for all form elements?

Comment: You can extend form builders. Even though it is not good, you can also put it in a constant in the model like `VIEW_PREFIX` and then in the form call `f.object.VIEW_PREFIX`